# How to convert React-Native mobile app to React web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app which runs for both Android and IOS platforms.

Can I convert the mobile app into a web app?

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Answer (score 9):

You can use React Native packages for Web like [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

`react-native-web` makes it possible to run React Native components and APIs on the web using React DOM.